# changing d3.JSON in Hierarchical Bars to JSON.parse

Tags: d3.js

I'm using http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663

and I'm trying to change the following code

```
d3.json("readme.json", function(root) {
  hierarchy.nodes(root);
  x.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 0);
});
```

to a JSON.parse (some data).  I don't have a problem pulling the JSON data but I am totally confused about what is being setup in the rest of the d3.json process with the hierarchy.node(root), x.domain and down(root)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to have to read a little more documentation before having a working understanding of what's going in this function. This is a tricky example to start with; I'm just going to walk you through what my process of trying to understand would look like. Going line by line:

```
d3.json("readme.json", function(root) {
```

This loads the referenced [json file](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1283663/790629437b261441cdc4b4ffe265e253db1e7232/readme.json) and calls function with it. 'root' starts out equal to the json file.

```
  hierarchy.nodes(root);
```

Looking through the code, we find where hierarchy is declared:

```
var hierarchy = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });
```

So hierarchy is some kind of [layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout) and [hierarchy.nodes](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Partition-Layout#wiki-nodes) will add some useful attributes to root that will make it easier to graph.

```
  x.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
```

searching for "x" in the example we find `x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w])`. Tt appears that x is a [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear). Basically, the x function will transform values in the domain - `[0, root.value]` to the range `[0, w]`. w is the width of the svg. root.value is a little trickier. The node page says

> value - the node value, as returned by the value accessor

But what is the value accessor? The initial declaration of indicates it has something todo with root's 'size' attribute, but what? At this point, the documentation starts to get pretty confusing so you might want to pop open the debugger and see exactly what the value attribute of root and root's children looks like.

```
down(root, 0);
```

The down function is unique to the example and well commented. Try reading through it while referencing the documentation and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks  that helps So basically I replaced 

d3.json("readme.json", function(root) {
  hierarchy.nodes(root);
  x.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 0);
});

with  

  hierarchy.nodes(json);
    x.domain([0, json.value]).nice();
    down(json, 0);

right?